# Pivot shows single record field value that doesn't agree to tabualr data model value (source data) - misaligned?

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have found something I'm a little concerned about.  Was trying to get a measure working and had it as a calc column previously so was comparing the 2 different outputs and checking for line by line differences.  I picked a good one and investigated.  calc column value was zero, measure value was £42.  The calc column is correct.  So i drilled into my measure to see what i could find.  Alarmingly, I found that for a certain field called DocumentStatus the pivot showed it as "LIVE".  But if I go to the table in visual studio and find that order the status is "COMPLETED".  I have checked and rechecked.  There is only 1 order on this table with the right DocumentNo.  The pivot seems to think this order is LIVE but the source data definitely shows it as completed.  What???  How can this happen?

So strictly speaking the measure is actually calculating correctly because it is seeing the order as live therefore picking the £42 value is correct for that formula.  The calc column is correct because it is seeing the order as completed so picking zero as the final value is correct.

It is the fact that the record is being seen as both live and completed that is throwing me.  I'm concerned to say the least.  This feels like a bug.  I have checked and have no other filters in play.   I have checked other ways too - like filtering on all orders with a £42 value in a particular field - none of the have a LIVE status.  Its almost like that field is misaligned in the background.

Has anyone ever seen this?

TIA

SSAS Tabular; SQL Server 2016, Visual Studio 2017

Edit 5 Jul:
Thanks for your comments.  Unfortunately I cannot provide sample data due to strict confidentiality.  I have provided 2 screen shots below, both showing the same record - (1) is the view from the excel pivot table that is connected to the ssas tabular data model (2) is the view of the table in Visual Studio (note how the value of the Accrued Income measure in this view is not the same as the AccruedIncome total in the excel pivot table)

I am wondering if this is to do with the way that I have deployed recent edits to the data model.  Every time I make a change I am running the deploy & build commands so that I can refresh the excel reports to see if they are working as intended.  What I don't know is when I do this am I deploying the metadata only or the metadata and the actual data (several hundred thousand rows on a dozen or so tables)?  Is the issue here that the pivot is looking at an older set of data than the dataset visual studio is looking at?  When I deploy & build do I then need to process the SSAS tabular object to update the data?

Also note how the DocumentStatus is different in the 2 views.

[Excel pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae2Nh.jpg)

[Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueEPM.jpg)

Comment: The only way anyone would be able to help you with this is if you provide actual data that can be looked at (e.g. table values, the query you're using to pull the data and the result you're getting).

Comment: It does sound like a bug, but it is not proof the bug exists in the products you have listed. Something is not right in your application - or the method you are using  verify the application. Without facts and figures - **here in the question** - we just cannot offer anything of much worth to you.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share the data due to strict confidentiality reasons.  Very difficult to anonymise it too.  I will try to make up for this with screen shots and further explanation.

Comment: I am a ssas tabular newbie so please bear with me.  I have run the deploy and build commands so my model is on the production server.  What I have not got to grips with yet is how to make changes to the data model.  So for example last night I edited the visual studio project and the ran the deploy and build commands again.  Does this deploy the metadata only or the actual data too?

Comment: I'm wondering if my issue described above is because I'm seeing up to date data in visual studio but the ssas tabular server has an older version of the data hence the difference between my excel pivot (connected to ssas tabular data model) and my table view on visual studio?